# Component gateway enable issues with dataproc cluster thru terraform

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-dataproc, api-gateway, terraform-provider-gcp

I spin up a dataproc cluster on gcp thru terraform, but I noticed that the component gateway still shows disabled though I had my scripts to enable it.

```
    software_config {
      optional_components   = [ "ANACONDA", "JUPYTER" ]
      image_version         = "${var.cluster_version}"
      override_properties   = {
        "dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers" = "true"
        "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable" = "true"
        "dataproc:dataproc.enable_component_gateway" = "true"
      }
    }
```

While looking up the references, it seems this feature can not be enabled thru terraform and there were also mentions of using endpoint gateway as below,

```
  endpoint_config {
    enable_http_port_access = "true"
  }
```

But when I tried using this, It error-ed out as "**invalid or unknown key: endpoint_Config**" .

Is there any other alternative to get this enabled thru terraform (note: i am using google-beta)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Terraform provider is out of sync with Dataproc API. If you would, please file a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google)

For the time being, you may have to create the cluster with CG manually.